# What is the purpose of verb reduplication?

Tags: meaning

In English, we can say:

I sneezed a big sneeze.
She sleeps a long sleep.
"Waiting for a king to apologize, one can wait rather a long wait." (from the film The Kings Speech)

and many more such examples.

Just one chapter of  西游记 has these five reduplications with  了 between.

Do you think the word after 了 is a noun or a verb? What is the purpose of the reduplication?

猪八戒抬手指了指天，
孙悟空看了看猪八戒的大肚子，无奈地笑了笑说，
拿着金箍棒晃了晃，对准马屁股作势要打。
，强盗头目眼珠子转了转，
一边说还一边向着猪八戒挥了挥手里的金箍棒。

For comparison， 了 followed by a noun:

你要真的抢了我的东西，
，如果这辈子做了坏事
强盗头目得到了满意的答案，

Comment: search site with "verb reduplication"  get 14 hits, it （动词的重叠）is a basic grammar topic covered in any web grammar e.g. https://iris.unive.it/retrieve/handle/10278/39972/85072/carnGram22.23-53.pdf http://tcfl.tingroom.com/2014/11/5480.html etc, etc.

Comment: It simply means the action repeated. 指, 挥, 晃, 笑, 转 are all actions that repeated.

Answer (score 2):

The examples you gave are not verb reduplication

phrases like 笑笑，看看，走走 or 吃吃 are verb reduplication, it serves to indicate the verb is in a slight degree or a casual manner

> *I sneezed a big sneeze*
>
> *She sleeps a long sleep*

These are just a same word as verb, and then as noun (object) in a same sentence

- the first sneeze is a verb; the second sneeze is a noun
- the first sleep is a verb; the second sleep is a noun

了 is not a verb, it is a 'verb particle' that indicate 'completion of the action' or 'change of situation.

In your 西游记 examples

- 指 = point
- 指了= pointed (the pointing action is completed)
- 笑了笑 - the first 笑 is a verb; the second 笑 is a 'verb classifier' for counting how many times the subject smiled (since there is only one smile, the action is in a slight degree or casual manner)
- 晃了晃 - the first 晃 is a verb; the second 晃 is a 'verb classifier' for counting how many times 金箍棒 was swung (since there is only one swing, the action is in a slight degree or casual manner)
- 转了转 - the first 转 is a verb; the second 转 is a 'verb classifier' for counting how many times 眼珠子 was turned (since there is only one turn, the action is in a slight degree or casual manner)

*Since the second 笑, 晃 and 转 are verb classifiers, they work with counting words: 笑了(一)笑, 晃了(三)晃, 转了(八)转*

> 抢了我的东西 (seized my stuffs) - '抢了' is a completed action; 我的东西 is the object
>
> 抢我的东西 - (seize my stuffs) - '抢' is a verb; 我的东西 is the object (no indication of either the action is completed or not)

~

> '做了坏事' (have done bad thing) - '做了' is a completed action; '坏事' is the object
>
> '做坏事' (do bad thing) - '做' is a verb ; '坏事' is the object (no indication of either the action is completed or not)

~

> '得到了满意的答案' (have got a satisfied answer) - 得到了 is a completed action; 满意的答案 is the object
>
> '得到满意的答案' (get a satisfied answer) - 得到 is verb; 满意的答案 is the object (no indication of either the action is completed or not)

Comment: If you can count something, it is a noun, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: That's why it is called "verb classifier". it is for counting 'times' of an action happened. e.g. in "劈一劈"  the first '劈' is the verb itself, 一 is the counting word (once) the second 劈 is the 'verb classifier' that indicates how many time the subject 'hacked'. You can say 'verb classifier' treating a verb like a noun

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding (I'm not a native Chinese) it's just a regular verb duplication. But, when it's duplicated in the past, the 了 particle is put in between the verbs.

我看看 = 我看一看 = 我看一下 = I'll take a look.
我看了看 = 我看了一看 = 我看了一下 = I took a look.